# проверка на время js

Tags: javascript, дата

```
var day = new Date();
let time = day.getHours().toString();   
if( time > 8 && time < 23){
    window.write('<span class="on">Работает</span>');
}else{
    window.write('<span class="off">Не работает</span>');
}
```

Должна быть проверка на время, то есть если время больше 8 и меньше 23 то условие. Время беру из метода `Date()`. Скрипт не работает, хотелось бы узнать в чем проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У объекта `window` нет метода `write`.

Имейте в виду, что диапазон значений, возвращаемых `getHours`, - от нуля то 23-х.

```js
var day = new Date();
let time = day.getHours().toString();
if (time > 8 && time < 23) {
  document.write('<span class="on">Работает</span>');
} else {
  document.write('<span class="off">Не работает</span>');
}
```

Comment: а как я могу вывести текст? типа print у php

Comment: @EmilRotatew Нажнмите на кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.